# If I set all fields of an object to null will it be killed from the Garbage Collector?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If, I set all fields of an object to null, it implies that the object is also set to null? Will it be collected from the Garbage Collector then?

Comment: No the object still exist. You must set the variable pointing to the object to `null` to achieve the desired action.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Java Garbage collector will only remove objects for which there are no valid references.

Setting all the fields of an object to `null` does not reduce the reference count of the object itself. It may, however, allow the GC to remove the objects that those fields once referenced, if those fields were the only (or last) reference to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM's garbage collector removes the objects where the reference is lost (due to which the program is unable to reach the object).

If you set the field of an object to null it will not affect the reference. So GC would not delete the object.

An automatic garbage collector essentially performs two tasks:

1. decide if and when memory needs to be reclaimed
2. find objects that are no longer needed by the program and reclaim
   their storage

A program has no guarantees that the automatic garbage collector will be run during its execution. A program should not rely on the scheduling of the automatic garbage collector for its behavior

[know about The Garbage collection](http://etutorials.org/Misc/programmers+guide+java+certification/Chapter+8.+Object+Lifetime/8.1+Garbage+Collection/)